# Proving that the group action of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ over a set $X$ is well defined

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am trying to prove Cauchy theorem for groups which states that:

If $G$ is a finite group, $|G| =n$, and $p$ a prime number which is a divisor of $n$, then there exists $g\in G$ such that $g^p =1$.

I am following a proof which defines an action over the following set:

$X = \{ (a_1,\cdots,a_p): a_1\cdots a_p =1, a_i\in G, i =1,\cdots,p\}$.

Then we define an action of $(\mathbb{Z_p},+)$ over $X$ by: 
$t\in \mathbb{Z_p},$

$t\cdot(a_1,\cdots,a_p) = (a_{t+1},a_{t+2},\cdots,a_t) $ where the subindexes in the second equality are taken modulo $p$.

I can see why  the action shall be well-defined: for example, since $a_1\cdots a_p = 1$, this implies that $a_2\cdots a_{p} = a_{1}^{-1}$, which also implies that $a_2\cdots a_pa_{1} = 1$, that is, $1\cdot(a_1,\cdots,a_p)\in X.$

But how to prove it with more **generality?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $1$ is a generator of $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, that solves the problem. By induction I can prove that if $G=\langle g \rangle $, then $g^{k}\cdot x \in X, x\in X, k\in Z$. Hence, since $1$ is a generator and its action is well defined, then all of its potencies action also will be well defined and therefore the whole group action.

Comment: We need not have that $G=\langle g\rangle$, i.e., that $G$ is cyclic.